# use of "as that of" as comparative and possessive case following it

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, possessives

which of the following usage are right ?

1) The life of the rich is as peaceful as that of the poor.
2) the life of the rich is as peaceful as that of the poor's.

3) Your bicycle is as beautiful as that of his.
4) your bicycle is as beautiful as that of him.

now if second sentence is wrong then third sentence should also be wrong. 
please explain. I have seen many a time a possessive case followed by "as that of" . so when can we use a possessive case after " as that of"

Answer (score 0):

No, you'd need to write them as follows:

> 1) The lives of the rich are as peaceful as those of the poor.
>
> 2) Your bicycle is as beautiful as his.

For the first sentence, you can't talk about the "life" of the rich, because "the rich" is plural, referring to "rich people". Correspondingly, you need to use "those" instead of "that" to match the plurality.

For the second sentence, yours is needlessly verbose and awkward. The version I've offered here is grammatically correct and compact.